# First, second and third conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

I found this sentence in my workbook:

> If you were a king, what'd your wife be called?"

Why was the ‘second conditional’ used here? That situation is completely *impossible*, so I think, it should be the ‘third conditional’:

> If you had been a king, what your wife would have been called?

Another example of a sentence which I found:

> What would you do if you needed a haircut?

It's in the ‘second conditional’, so it should be an *unlikely* situation, but for me, it's really *possible*, so I would use the ‘first conditional’:

> What will you do if you need a haircut?

I don't understand that.

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from “If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”, Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, ELT Journal 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press, doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Comment: "First, second, and third conditional" are not standard terms, and only your classmates will know what you mean by them. You seem to be following rules that nobody else believes in, so you're probably not going to get a satisfying answer here. Sorry about that.

Comment: You cannot contract *what would* into *what’d* as you have done there. Furthermore, the second version of *what your wife would have been called?* is not English at all because the word order is wrong. You might prefer to visit our sister site for [ell.se].

Comment: Time and time again I see users dismissing questions because some poor soul  uses the terms zero, 1st, 2nd, and 3rd conditional. Why is there this pretence of not knowing what they mean? Why the disparagement, and refusal to acknowledge their existence? These terms, whether we like it or not, are taught to language learners, specifically at pre-intermediate and intermediate levels. I *know* that conditionals cannot be packaged in three or four boxes, but that's how they're taught, and the explanations that accompany them are pretty valid nonetheless.

Comment: ***I*** don't in fact know what those terms mean, @Mari-Lou. They're not used by grammarians, nor taught in school grammars in the United States. It sounds like they are indeed taught to language learners, somewhere, but without definitions and examples (and not just silly names with irrelevant numbers attached), I can't do a thing. Where does this pretense of the universality of these terms come from?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this can't be the first time you have encountered these terms @JohnLawler. I realize that it is not taught at native schools, grammar rarely is nowadays, but this form of classification has been taught to language learners for maybe twenty years or more. There's even a conditional tense called "mixed", so that makes it five :) I just find it so frustrating and sad that so many choose to dismiss people's questions on conditionals because these learners have been taught to label them with numbers. It's not their fault, is it?

Comment: And if I were a grammar maven, which I'm not, I would like to help.

Comment: No, it's not their fault. But as I said, all I have are names. I am a grammar maven, and I would like to help, but I don't read minds. Are there decriptions and examples anywhere that are official in this pocket grammar of English? If they're that common, where are they?

Comment: "Traditional" school—1. http://www.englishtenses.com/conditional_sentences and one English language website which doesn't use the numbering system— 2. http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/conditionalintro.html

Comment: @Mari-LouA The problem isn’t so much that people are being taught first/second/third/fourth/mixed conditional, but that different schools/people/countries use the terms to mean different things. I’ve seen people use a 0–3 system, a 1–3 system, a 1–4 system, a 1–5 system—even a top/middle/bottom system (which made even less sense to me than the others). And sometimes what’s a first conditional to one school will be a third conditional to another school. There is so much variation and contradiction that it really is necessary to include the definitions used in each question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not aware of these differences, usually the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd conditionals are always mentioned in textbooks, sometimes the so-called zero, and finally, and only at more Advanced levels the so-called "mixed conditionals". I don't know if this classification is universal, I was under the impression it was, I have never heard of the "top/middle/bottom system" in my life, but I'd guess it's just another way of saying 3rd, 2nd, and first/zero conditional.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Admittedly, I have only encountered the top/middle/bottom one once or twice, in China. I just found it so extremely bizarre that I remembered it.

Comment: @Mary-Lou. Well said. I am also a little tired of the automatic disparagement that accompanies any question daring to ask about the _n-conditionals_. For those unfamiliar with ELL pedagogy the 4 commonly taught patterns are: _Zero conditional_: If he asks for money, I give it to him. _First conditional_: If he asks for money, I will give it to him. _Second conditional_: If he asked for money, I would give it to him. _Third conditional_: If he had asked for money, I would have given it to him.

Comment: @Shoe Precisely what part of ***“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage”*** needs clarification?

Comment: @tchrist, I think we are at cross-purposes. My point is not that there are only three or four ways of expressing conditions in English. Clearly, this would be a ludicrous position. What I am saying is that pedagogic grammars and ELT textbooks commonly introduce conditional statements or hypotheticals by means of three common verb "tense" combinations, which they designate first, second, and third conditionals - as I exemplify in my first comment. These are the terms that learners use when they come to this site and ask questions. ...

Comment: [cont] You could argue of course that any question that includes the terms should by definition be migrated to ELL, because the asker is more than likely a non-native speaker, and may get a better response there than here.

Comment: So, outlaw any question by any non-native speaker that specifically asks about grammar? If someone asks about the subjunctive, which is practically obsolete in the UK that's OK. But if someone asks about the "second" or "third conditional" they should get shoved off to ELL, where many users who answer these type of question  (not *everyone*) are non-native speakers in the first place.

Comment: @Mary-Lou. My tongue was firmly in my cheek with my automatic migration suggestion! Actually, I am far from convinced that we need a separate site for English language learners. There are very basic questions about English and very advanced ones, and I don't see why these cannot coexist on one site. We answerers can choose which ones interest us and we are competent to answer.

Comment: Thank you for the references, @Mari-Lou. I have looked at the sites that you recommended above.  The zero-3 system seems to be much more complex than needed (as well as incorrect and incomplete). I'm glad I never had to teach an ESL class with that kind of nonsense in the textbook. Now I will recognize it when I see it; but I'll still have to say that it's not a correct analysis of English conditionals, and that it doesn't seem to explain anything better than a correct analysis wouid. Sounds like a tradition that's too sacred to ignore.

Comment: @JohnLawler it would be a great service if you would explain (perhaps in a question that you answer yourself) why "The zero-3 system seems to be much more complex than needed (as well as incorrect and incomplete)" instead of simply badmouthing the terms/system as is your wont. ESL teachers and students everywhere await your help.

Comment: @pazzo: I don't need to. It's already been done, as tchrist kindly pointed out in the very first comment above, which I should have read first. For the benefit of ESL teachers and students everywhere, here's that link again: http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf

Comment: @pazzo I think it is unnecessary to be rude. I am of the opinion that teaching the conditionals as separate units is helpful in the beginning, but there is the real risk that teachers, and grammarians, and learners either oversimplify or over complicate this aspect of grammar. The link tchrist provided is actually worth reading, especially the paragraphs entitled **Teaching Implications** and **teaching approaches**. But at the same time, learners who ask questions using the four terms are not to be ignored or told to "forget" everything they have been taught so far, because it is a lie.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try and do my best to answer this question, in such a way that you'll be able to make some sense out of this, and then apply these guidelines in the future.

The first sentence is an example of the so-called *second conditional*

> If ***you were*** a king, what'd your wife be called?

Rightly so, edyta—the OP—said this is an impossible situation. The chances of edyta, whom I presume is a woman, becoming king is even more remote. But the sentence doesn't refer to a `past` event. Being a king never happened and it never will.  The idiomatic phrase **If** + **you** + **were** is expressing an *unreal* situation, similar to saying: *Let's pretend you are a king.*

The construction   **If + subject + past** and **would + infinitive**  is often referred to as *irrealis*, which means that the situation proposed is ‘unreal’ or ‘imaginary’ `in the present`
<sub>See also [Present Unreal Conditional](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/presentconditional.html)</sub>

The past verb-form is used to suggest that the situation is probable, or imaginary, or set in a hypothetical future.

Martin Parrott provides this insight:

> We use them [type 2 conditional sentences] to refer to or speculate about something that is (or that we perceive to be) impossible or ‘contrary to fact’. This is sometimes presented to learners as ‘very unlikely’. The real point, however, is that at the moment of speaking we see the action or event as being impossible.
>
> <sup>Source: Grammar for English Language Teachers</sup>

- *Probable*; e.g. “If I were on holiday, I'd go to the beach every day.”
- *Imaginary*; e.g. “If I were a cat, I'd catch mice all day long.”
- Or *hypothetical future* event; e.g. “If I had a car, we would drive down to Mexico.”

The OP's example falls under the category of **imaginary**, *If I were a King. . .*

The following sentence is an example of a hypothetical future event

> A: What would you do **if you needed** a haircut?
>
> i. I'd go to the hairdresser's.
> ii. I'd cut it myself.
> iii. I don't know. Cut it, I guess. Why are you asking?

---

The so-called ‘third conditional’  is for talking about a hypothetical/imaginary situation in the **past** (which didn't happen) and its consequence.

*If you had worked harder last year, you would have passed your exam*
**if + past perfect** and **would have** + **past participle**
<sub>See also: [Past Unreal Conditional](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/pastconditional.html)</sub>

Thus the sentence (note my correction on the word order)

> If you had been king, what **would** your wife **have been** called?

Expresses either an imaginary situation `in the past` that didn't happen, or an event that didn't happen `in the past`. In both cases, the situation is ‘impossible’ because we cannot change the past.

Comment: “It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.” It’s an ESL myth that is not taught to native speakers (Thank Goodness!) nor is it used by linguists, since it doesn’t make sense because it does not reflect actual usage. That means this is strictly an ESL bug and so belongs on [ell.se].

Comment: @tchrist I was never taught the conditionals at school, no one in the UK was taught about them (pre 1980s). I just knew how to say 'em, without even knowing what they were called, and I'd wager this is true for most native North American speakers too. You don't *need* to study grammar in order to speak a native language.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: North American native speakers also know how to say them without being taught them, but a number of U.S. dialects get them "wrong".

Comment: @Mari-Lou And I would have used an incorrect example in the previous comment if I would have thought of a good one before the editing time ran out. Writing in non-standard dialect is ***hard*** here because it's not just a matter of adding *would* to any standard conditional construction.

Comment: @PeterShor Are American children taught how to write conditional sentences at school? Do they have books with examples and explanations? I am specifically asking about children in middle school i.e. aged somewhere between 10 and 13.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I suspect that in regions where the non-standard construction is common (I think the Upper Midwest is one of them), they are covered. I didn't have any instruction on them when I was going to school (D.C., 1970s), and my daughters don't seem to have gotten any instruction on them in New England, either.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you.  And if you had to teach the conditional to a group of non-native speakers aged between 11 and 16 how would you approach it? Would you?

Comment: I think ESL teachers have to lie. If they didn't lie, ESL would be too complicated. But they could say *"these are the most common uses of the conditional we're teaching you. There are also mixed conditionals, but those are much rarer so you can learn them later"*

Comment: And that is more or less what I tell my private students after they passed the two year barrier. You wouldn't teach this to a complete beginner, you couldn't!

Comment: It *might* be worth noting that *would* is just the default auxiliary verb in these conditionals; you *could* also use the preterite form of almost any other auxiliary verb if it fit your meaning. Anyone seeking to master English *should* learn this.

Comment: When teaching ESL/EFL one has to start somewhere. Erecting a temporary scaffolding that can help learners understand certain sentence patterns is quite helpful and practical. Telling students that these are not the only possibilities is also being frank. And linguists who won't come down their off their high horse to meet/interact/assist language teachers and learners risk  coming across as highfalutin with no interest in helping the community.

Comment: But does it actually help them understand anything? How many "pass the two-year barrier" and get cleared for reality? It appears the OP didn't benefit from being able to recognize which number conditional was being applied.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Is it just my imagination, or is all this bloviation about a simple 2-by-2 paradigm with Past/Present and Hypothetical/Counterfactual as the dimensions? It seems like that's the concept people are dancing around, but nobody's said so exactly. I can't get a handle on the forms, and how much of the paradigm is about meaning instead of grammar.

Comment: @JohnLawler learners can recognize a sentence is in the simple past, that doesn't mean they don't make mistakes in their assumptions, or in their rationalizations.  The fact that edyta does not take everything at face value is promising, and healthy. The question shows a desire to understand, but like anything else in life, new notions and skills need time before they are assimilated.

Answer (score 1):

"If you had been a king, what your wife would have been called?" has the sense of referring to a [specific] time that occurred in the listener's past, which makes it completely impossible -- because we cannot change the past.

"If you were a king, what'd your wife be called?" asks a hypothetical question about a situation that, while unlikely, could still happen in theory and could very easily take place in the imagination, dreams, story-telling, fiction, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the second and third conditional is ***not*** whether it is possible or not, but whether it's set in the present or the past.

> If you were a flying unicorn, what color would you be?

Second conditional because it's set in the present, even though it's completely impossible.

> If William Quantrill had buried a quarter of a million dollars in gold during the Civil War, where would he have put it?

Third conditional, because it's set in the past, even though it's remotely possible. (Although it's clear that the speaker thinks Quantrill's gold is indeed a myth. If he thought it were likely, he would have used *buried* instead of *had buried*.)

Comment: “If a unicorn pooped here then where’s the smell?” :)

Comment: Being "set" in a particular time is not a grammatical but a discourse phenomenon. Tense and time are not the same things. _Were_ is a past tense form, any way you look at it (unless you get a papal dispensation). If it's demonstrably past tense, but not "set" in the past, what are the tests for determining the "setting"?

Answer (score 0):

*"If you were a king, what'd your wife be called?"* **[present time**

*"If you had been a king, what your wife would have been called?"*  **[past time**

Comment: *What'd* is short for *what did*, not *what would*.